# How to make sencha components width device independent

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I created register panel and added toolbar with button during view initialization, In controller i am creating form panel and adding it to the register panel dynamically.

The toolbar in register panel is adjusting based on device screen but, The form panel width is not changing.

If i set width for the form panel, The form panel is floating and width remains the same.

This is what i done so for.

```
   Ext.define('Form.view.RegisterForm',{
    extend : 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype : 'register',
    id : 'register',

    initialize : function() { 
        console.log("register init");
        var submit = {
            xtype : 'button',
            width : '100px',
            ui : 'action',
            text : 'Submit',
            handler : this.onSubmitTap,
            scope : this
        };

        var topToolbar = {
            xtype : 'toolbar',
            docked : 'top',
            id : 'registerToolbar',
            title : 'Form',
            items : [{
                xtype : 'spacer'
            }, submit]
        };

        this.add(topToolbar);
    },
    config : {
        fullscreen : true,
        layout : {
            type : 'vbox'
        },
        title : 'Register'
    },

    onSubmitTap : function() {
        console.log("onSubmit");
        this.fireEvent('submitCommand', this);
    }

});
```

In Register controller i adding fields dynamically

```
 // RegisterFormController.js

    oncreateForm : function() {
            var form = {
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    flex : 1,
                    id: formId,
                    name: formId
                };
            Ext.getCmp('register').add(form);

    }

// calling  onCreateComponent method with xtype, label, value and fromId 

        onCreateComponent : function(fxtype,flabel,fname,fvalue,id) {
            Ext.getCmp(id).add({
                xtype: fxtype,
                label: flabel,
                name: fname,
                value: fvalue,
                labelWrap:true
            });
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: you can try layout:'fit' to register panel.

Comment: @NareshTank, i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case any of you came up with same problem.

The mistake i did was "I added the 4 radio buttons in a hbox panel so width of that panel increased that's why the whole form panel not displaying properly in different devices".

After i changed the panel layout as vbox, The problem solved.